# Timestamp not Appearing in Azure Table Storage Query Result Entities in Python

Tags: python, azure

I am querying an Azure Data Table using Python:

```
# create azure table storage client
table_client = TableClient.from_connection_string(conn_str=key1, table_name="Table")

# query table
entities = table_client.query_entities(f"Timestamp ge datetime'{start_date}' and Timestamp le datetime'{end_date}'")

entity_list = []
for entity in entities:
    entity_list.append(entity)
```

Everything works as expected, except my result does not contain the Timestamp field.

How am I able to include the Timestamp in the query result?

Comment: (f"Timestamp ge datetime{start_date} and Timestamp le datetime {end_date}")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For anyone coming back to this question in the future, a solution is to fetch the timestamp from the entity metadata:

```
# create azure table storage client
table_client = TableClient.from_connection_string(conn_str=key1, table_name="Table")

# query table
entities = table_client.query_entities(f"Timestamp ge datetime'{start_date}' and Timestamp le datetime'{end_date}'")

entity_list = []
for entity in entities:
    timestamp = entity._metadata["timestamp"]
    entity_list.append(entity)
```

Comment: The entity also has a public `metadata` attribute that would be more reliable to access; see this issue response in the Python SDK repo: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues/31992#issuecomment-1720559127

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the SDK source code [`here`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/db129d0020160815d2a5cd52be5b6777a6cbefaf/sdk/tables/azure-data-tables/azure/data/tables/_deserialize.py#L133), it looks the SDK is not including the `Timestamp` property in the resulting entity. The code is setting the `PartitionKey` (line 168) and `RowKey` (line 173) properties but not the `Timestamp` property.

I believe your best bet would be to raise an issue here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues and ask the team to include this property in the resulting entity.